# How to take path name from pandas data frame and pass it into the pd.read_csv to read that file with the path?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, path, operating-system

What I did was use

```
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for subdirectory in subdirectories:
        print(os.path.join(root, subdirectory))
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
        dataframe1 = dataframe1.append({"Directory":root,"FileName":file}, ignore_index=True)
```

to get all of the path names and put it into a dataframe. I basically manipulated the data in the data frame in order to find the relevant path for today. I saved it into a csv file and tried to get the name of the path in a list by using

```
def listToString(path): 
    
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = "" 
    
    # traverse in the string  
    for ele in path: 
        str1 += ele  
    
    # return string  
    return str1 
        
    a = listToString(path)
    print(a)
```

I then tried to use `pd.read_csv(print(a))` in order to get the file path for the file I want to read but keep getting an error. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the value of `a`? And do you want `pd.read_csv(print(a))` or `pd.read_csv(a)`? 
Also, shouldn't you already have the file paths you need from `os.walk`?

Comment: upload a sample of your csv (as file or text) and then show us your expected output also

Comment: The value of a is r'\\path\path\path\path\path\path\20212907-1248\File_Name.csv'. I would ideally like pd.read_csv(a) but when I try to do that it returns the wrong path so the pd.read does not output anything, just an error saying it can't find the path. I did not put the actual path here but basically I want to make it so that i am given the right path for each day as it changes daily so I thought pandas would be a good way to do it.